# Standard deviation of the postion and momentum for the coherent state of an harmonic oscilator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Consider a particle of mass $m$ under an harmonic potential, $V=\frac12 kx^2$.
The coherence states

$$\psi_\alpha=e^{-{{1}\over{2}}|\alpha|^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{{\alpha^n}\over{\sqrt{n!}}}\psi_n$$

where $\psi_n$ are the energy eigenfunctions, are eigenfunctions of the annihilation operator ($â \psi_\alpha =\alpha\psi_\alpha$).
How could I determine the standard deviation of the position and momentum of the particle in state $\psi_\alpha$?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158849/harmonic-oscillator-coherent-state-expectation-values