# Variance of a hermitian operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

Take an hermitian operator $O$ such that $O|\psi\rangle = x|\psi\rangle$. The variance of an operator $O$ is defined as
$$ (\Delta O)^2 = \langle{O^2}\rangle - \langle{O}\rangle^2.$$
Let's consider the first term, I would write it as

$$ \langle{O^2}\rangle  = \langle\psi|O O|\psi\rangle = x\langle\psi|O|\psi\rangle = x^2\langle\psi|\psi\rangle = x^2.$$
But then for the second term I get the same result
$$\langle{O}\rangle^2  = \langle\psi| O|\psi\rangle^2 = (x\langle\psi|\psi\rangle)^2 = x^2.$$
Therefore I end up with $(\Delta O)^2 = 0$ which is obviously wrong. What's the problem here?

The only idea I have is that $O^2|\psi\rangle \neq O(O|\psi\rangle)$, but i cannot understand why...
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have written things, the variance is indeed $0$ because $\vert\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $O$: thankfully this is so as it means the outcome with eigenvalue $x$ is not uncertain and we can use the eigenvalue $x$ to label the state.

Comment: Thanks, make sense, but then I have a problem somewhere else: I'm trying to calculate the variance of the field quadratures on a coherent state, with your reasoning the coherent state is an eigenstate of the quadrature operators and therefore the variance is 0, which is not what I expect....

Comment: @user85231 The coherent state is an eigenstate of $\hat a$, which is not hermitian.  The variance is not $0$ in this case. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158849/harmonic-oscillator-coherent-state-expectation-values