# Question regarding the expected value of the momentum of a Gauß distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, coherent-states

Given the position amplitude
$$\psi(q) = \frac1{\sqrt{L \sqrt{\pi}}} 
e^{-\frac1{2}\left(\frac{q-q_0}{L}\right)^2}
$$ I get the expected value for the position $$\langle \hat{q} \rangle = q_0$$ which makes sense to me but the expected value for momentum I get $$\langle \hat{p} \rangle = 0$$ which for me is kind of unintuitive. Is there a reasonable explanation of why this is the case? A Gauß distribution in my eyes should be one where the particle is the most localized (and the distribution with the lowest uncertainty) but shouldn't you still expect a non-zero momentum? To add to that, if u multiply a complex exponential function so u get
$$
\psi(q) = \frac1{\sqrt{L \sqrt{\pi}}} 
e^{-\frac1{2}\left(\frac{q-q_0}{L}\right)^2} e^{i k_0 q}
$$ u also get a non-zero expected value for the momentum being $$\langle \hat{p} \rangle = \hbar k_0.$$ How can u interpret this physically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course you can take the Fourier transform of $\psi(q)$ to get $\psi(p)$, and you will find $\langle p\rangle=0$ but intuitively
$$
\psi(q)=\frac1{\sqrt{L \sqrt{\pi}}} e^{-\frac1{2}\left(\frac{q-q_0}{L}\right)^2}
$$
is solution to the *time-independent* Schrödinger equation (in a harmonic potential) so that $\langle x\rangle$ will be independent of $t$.  You can then think that
$\langle p\rangle = m\langle \dot{x}\rangle =m\frac{d}{dt}\langle x\rangle=0$.

The second case, where you have shifted your Gaussian (in $p$-space) is no longer a solution to the TISE but in fact a *[coherent state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state#The_wavefunction_of_a_coherent_state)* and it's expectation values for $\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle p\rangle$ are discussed [in this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158849/36194).

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation that makes alot of sense

Answer (score 1):

$p$ can be positive or negative and when you average, they cancel.   $\sqrt{<\hat p^2>}$ will give the sort of answer you would expect.